# Arguments of collinear complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

This is the exact passage give in my book about collinear complex numbers, I think there is an error somewhere. Would someone please explain the real conditions for arguments of collinear complex numbers? The passage seems rather contradictory as it first says that for collinearity arg (z1/z2) = π implying arg z1 - arg z2 = π or arg z1 = arg z2, and then says that definitely arg z1 = arg z2.

> If origin O, z1, z2 are collinear and z1, z2 lie on same side of origin then arg z1 = arg z2 and arg (z1/z2) = 0. If O, z1, z2 are collinear and z1 and z2 are on opposite sides of origin then arg (z1/z2) = π. Hence if z1, O, z2 are collinear then  z1/z2 is purely real. This is to say that if |z1+z2| = |z1| + |z2| then arg z1 = arg z2

Comment: One way you can check is with concrete examples. For example, try it out with $1+i$ and $3+3i$, similarly with $1+i$ and $-3-3i$ and see what happens

Comment: @imranfat I'm so sorry to ask such a silly question but how did you get those points? What line are they part of? And though I rather intuitively feel that they must be on opposite sides of the origin, how do we know for sure?

Comment: I made them up, but they are collinear, right?

Comment: @imranfat yes they are, I just wanted to know how you knew that they were collinear, since I don't think I could have thought them up on my own. How did you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in what is stated. Simply the conclusion,

> If $|z1+z2| = |z1| + |z2|$ then arg $(z_1) = $ arg$(z_2)$

does not purely logically follow from what precedes.

One would still have to explain why $$|z1+z2| = |z1| + |z2|$$
occurs if and only if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are collinear and on the same side of the origin. It is true, but not explained here.

Comment: Would you please explain why |z1+z2| is not equal to |z1| + |z2| for all collinear lines? Isn't that the basic definition of collinearity( eg: if A, B, C are collinear AC = AB + BC?

Comment: @Hema For instance $z$ and $-z$ are collinear, but $|z+(-z)|=0\neq|z|+|-z|$. The definition of collinearity is $z_1, z_2$ are collinear $\Leftrightarrow\exists a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $az_1+bz_2=0$, and $a,b$ not both zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $z_1, z_2, 0$ are col-linear there are two cases

$z_1,z_2$ are on the same side of the origin

$\arg z_1 = \arg z_2\\
\frac {z_1}{z_2} = \frac {|z_1|}{|z_2|}\\
\arg \frac {z_1}{z_2} = \arg 1 = 0\\
$

$\frac {z_1}{z_2}$ is real

Or the origin is between $z_1$ and $z_2$

$\arg z_1 - \arg z_2 = \pm \pi\\
\frac {z_1}{z_2} = -\frac {|z_1|}{|z_2|}\\
\arg \frac {z_1}{z_2} = \arg -1 = \pi\\
$

$\frac {z_1}{z_2}$ is real

Draw an example of each of the two cases....
[image]